# List files whose name contains a date string with python

Tags: python

I have this code to list files like '*20150304.csv' but returns nothing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
dir_local = '/var/log/'

import os
import glob
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
YEST = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

glob_pattern='*YEST.csv'

for fname in glob.glob(dir_local + os.sep + glob_pattern):
    print fname
```

However, when i replace with

```
for fname in glob.glob('/var/log/' + os.sep + '*20150304.csv'):
```

I get the desired result though the date will be changing everyday and hence need to list new files.
What can i do?

I have read this link [list is coming as blank in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494444/list-is-coming-as-blank-in-python) but we do not seen to have the same problem.

Comment: `YEST` is a variable, not a string? `global_pattern='*'+YEST+'.csv'`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanx a lot Torxed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
glob_pattern='*YEST.csv'
```

with:

```
glob_pattern = '*{0}.csv'.format(YEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to generate the current date (or yesterday's date?) as a string.  Try this:

```
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Now you can put that in your `glob`.